# using jquery to delay, then fade out and remove

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout

I have a dialog on a website im working on that im trying to get working by doing the following.

Its build using .append() waits 5 seconds then fadeout() and remove(). I wrote the following but it doesnt seem to work.

**html**

```
<div class="addAddressDialog"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**js**

```
    $(".addAddressDialog").append("<span> Thank you </span>")
     .delay(5000)
     .queue(function(next){
      $('.addAddressDialog, .overlay').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});                                
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/pAzyc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pAzyc/2/

Don't call `remove` in callback function

```
    $('.overlay').css("height",$(document).height());

    $(".addAddressDialog").append("<span> Thank you </span>").delay(5000).queue(function(next){
      $('.addAddressDialog, .overlay').fadeOut('fast').remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Little modyfied your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/shershen08/pAzyc/6/ so now it works. Problem was that $(this) pointed to only one element, but if you want to apply function to several elements you could use $.each